# Post-doc without much collaboration

Tags: postdocs

I am currently doing a Ph.D. and will be graduating soon. I have applied for many post-doc positions but untill now, I haven't received any offer. I may get an post-doc offer in my own country. The problem is, in my own country, there are few collaboration oppurtunties, although there are many great researchers. The field I have chosen in my PhD is quite on trend in my country. My goal is to get a job (assistant professor) in my own country. During my PhD I have published a few results but I need more papers to get a job. During my post-doc I need to publish 2-3 good papers in a year then only I am eligible for a assistant professor job in my country. In my country collaboration is less and in foreign country I am not getting post-doc. I am from asia. I can publish good papers at my own but not like 2-3 in a year.

**Question :** What I should do to increase my research paper output in post-doc If I don't have collaboration? Last thing I don't need publication in A* conferences, Even A level conferences are enough to get a job after post-doc.

I work in theoretical computer science.

Comment: You don't need to be colocated to have collaboration. Does the postdoc give you any freedom?

Comment: In general, I'd recommend that you travel and attend conferences a lot, if it's practical. I know the conference culture in CS is different than in my field; is it normal to attend conferences even if you don't have a new paper to present at each one?

Comment: You can publish faster with practice.  I think this question is unreasonably broad.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist True. but practise might take few more years. Currently even working hard I don't think I will be able to publish as much as required at my own in a year.

Comment: @academic I have talk to few researcher during conferences in the past but I don't know in the conference we can start a project but I will try to this in the comming conferences.

Comment: @I_wil_break_wall I'd recommend approaching researchers after their talks and asking questions. e.g. "You described how Technique X can be used to address Problem Y. Do you know if it's also relevant to Problem Z?" Maybe this will lead to a collaboration, but doing this kind of thing is usually good for its own sake.